# How do I configure Gmail Sync Accounts for iOS post January 2013?

Tags: ios, gmail, google-sync

At the end of January 2013 Google [dropped support for Gmail Sync](http://www.zdnet.com/google-drops-exchange-activesync-support-for-free-email-accounts-7000008836/) for nonpaying Gmail customers. I understood this drop in support to mean that no new devices could be setup, not that I could no longer configure existing devices. However, if there is still a way to affect the configuration of existing devices I cannot find it on Google's sync website.

Am I missing something? Is there a site I can visit to make configuration changes for devices?

Comment: I was wondering whether my post below answers your question or if there is something that still needs to be clarified... In the former case, I'd appreciate that you marked the question as answered, in the latter case, could you tell me what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

No, I wouldn't say you're missing anything. As you say, Google will continue to support any configured devices beyond January 31, 2013 (from http://googleblog.blogspot.ch/2012/12/winter-cleaning.html):

> Starting January 30, 2013, consumers won't be able to set up new
>   devices using Google Sync; however, *existing Google Sync connections
>   will continue to function*. Google Sync will continue to be fully
>   supported for Google Apps for Business, Government and Education.
>   Users of those products are unaffected by this announcement.

so no changes for your devices whatsoever (from http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936):

> **What do I need to do if I’m already using Google Sync?**
>
> Nothing! Existing users can continue to use Google Sync on their
>   current devices.
>
> **What will happen if I keep using Google Sync after January 30, 2013?**
>
> The service will continue to work for existing Google Sync devices.
>   Google Sync will continue to work, be supported, and take new sign-ups
>   for Google Apps for Business, Education, and Government customers.

For new devices, or if you wish to stop using Google Sync on your devices, check these links:

- CalDAV for iOS devices: http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151674
- CardDAV for iOS devices: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2753077

---

*As a side note:* Windows Phone users, on the contrary, got an extension and Google will accept new device connections until July 31, 2013 (from http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936):

[image]

See also this [blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/01/30/synching-google-services-with-windows-phone.aspx).